# React-Native fresh App immediately closes when launch on real devices

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I want to develop android app using **React-Native**, it works well on emulator, but when I try with real device, the app immediately closes when launch, even if it with fress `react-native init projectName`.

When I try to see at the Logcat, here is the result when I try to open the fresh app:

```
11-24 07:03:39.408 2007-2007/? E/PhoneStatusBar: updateNotificationTitleText  preIsInsidePanelCanSlide =true,misInsidePanelCanSlide = true,misInsidePanelOpen = false
11-24 07:03:40.068 2708-3433/? D/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDefaultSubscription, sub = 12
11-24 07:03:40.068 2708-3609/? D/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDefaultSubscription, sub = 12
11-24 07:03:40.098 2708-3600/? D/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDefaultSubscription, sub = 12
11-24 07:03:40.108 2708-3107/? D/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDefaultSubscription, sub = 12

    --------- beginning of system
11-24 07:03:40.118 1022-1042/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.library_app2/.MainActivity bnds=[286,87][539,358]} from uid 10059 and from pid 2779 on display 0
11-24 07:03:40.128 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.128 15968-15968/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: handleKeyguardVisibilityChanged mKeyguardViewManager = com.android.keyguard.KeyguardViewManager@12d66782
11-24 07:03:40.128 15968-15968/? D/KeyguardViewManager: handleKeyguardVisibilityChanged showing = true
11-24 07:03:40.138 1022-1042/? V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{3930ddf5 token=Token{148c1f2c ActivityRecord{272956df u0 com.library_app2/.MainActivity t1328}}} to stack=1 task=1328 at 0
11-24 07:03:40.138 1022-1060/? V/WindowManager: Based on layer: Adding window Window{3f5127c4 u0 Starting com.library_app2} at 5 of 15
11-24 07:03:40.148 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.158 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.168 26069-26069/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-24 07:03:40.168 1022-1904/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 26069:com.library_app2/u0a343 for activity com.library_app2/.MainActivity
11-24 07:03:40.168 1022-1904/? D/ActivityManager:  (1) delay start com.library_app2 startResult.usingWrapper false
11-24 07:03:40.208 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.348 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.348 1022-1904/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{1786b351 u0 com.oppo.launcher/com.oppo.launcher.Launcher} to null Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.handleAppTransitionReadyLocked:9943 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:10529 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop:9333 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked:9275 
11-24 07:03:40.348 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.348 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.358 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.368 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.368 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.378 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.378 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: init start
11-24 07:03:40.378 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: adding system library source: /vendor/lib
11-24 07:03:40.378 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: adding system library source: /system/lib
11-24 07:03:40.378 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.library_app2-1/lib/arm flags = 0]
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main flags = 1]
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib flags = 2]
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/vendor/lib flags = 2]
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.library_app2-1/lib/arm flags = 0]
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main flags = 1]
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: init finish: 4 SO sources prepared
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: init exiting
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at com.library_app2.MainApplication.initializeFlipper(MainApplication.java:61)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at com.library_app2.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:46)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4735)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:164)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1492)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5473)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.library_app2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.library_app2-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:   ... 16 more
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:       ... 17 more
11-24 07:03:40.388 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/System.err:   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
11-24 07:03:40.448 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: About to load: libjscexecutor.so
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so found on /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: Loading lib dependencies: [libfb.so, libreactnativejni.so, libjsc.so, libjsinspector.so, libfolly_json.so, libglog.so, libc++_shared.so, liblog.so, libc.so, libm.so, libdl.so]
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: About to load: libfb.so
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: Loading lib dependencies: [libc++_shared.so, liblog.so, libdl.so, libandroid.so, libc.so, libm.so]
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: About to load: libc++_shared.so
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libc++_shared.so found on /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: Loading lib dependencies: [libc.so, libdl.so]
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: About to load: libc.so
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libc.so not found on /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libc.so not found on /data/app/com.library_app2-1/lib/arm
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libc.so not found on /system/vendor/lib
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libc.so found on /system/lib
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libc.so loaded implicitly
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: Loaded: libc.so
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: About to load: libdl.so
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libdl.so not found on /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libdl.so not found on /data/app/com.library_app2-1/lib/arm
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libdl.so not found on /system/vendor/lib
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libdl.so found on /system/lib
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libdl.so loaded implicitly
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: Loaded: libdl.so
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 E/art: dlopen("/data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main/libc++_shared.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main/libc++_shared.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libc++_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main/libc++_shared.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libfb.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libc++_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main/libc++_shared.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
11-24 07:03:40.488 26069-26069/com.library_app2 E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libfb.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libc++_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main/libc++_shared.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
11-24 07:03:40.498 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
11-24 07:03:40.498 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: init exiting
11-24 07:03:40.558 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
11-24 07:03:40.568 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
11-24 07:03:40.598 26069-26069/com.library_app2 I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
11-24 07:03:40.598 26069-26069/com.library_app2 I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
11-24 07:03:40.608 26069-26101/com.library_app2 W/unknown:InspectorPackagerConnection: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry
11-24 07:03:40.608 26069-26100/com.library_app2 W/unknown:ReconnectingWebSocket: Couldn't connect to "ws://localhost:8081/message?device=R7sf%20-%205.1.1%20-%20API%2022&app=com.library_app2&clientid=DevSupportManagerImpl", will silently retry
11-24 07:03:40.608 26069-26099/com.library_app2 W/unknown:ReactNative: The packager does not seem to be running as we got an IOException requesting its status: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
11-24 07:03:40.638 26069-26105/com.library_app2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-24 07:03:40.638 1022-2005/? V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{39362e65 u0 com.library_app2/com.library_app2.MainActivity} at 2 of 16 (before Window{3f5127c4 u0 Starting com.library_app2})
11-24 07:03:40.648 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader()
11-24 07:03:40.648 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
11-24 07:03:40.648 26069-26069/com.library_app2 D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
11-24 07:03:40.648 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.668 26069-26069/com.library_app2 W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
11-24 07:03:40.668 26069-26107/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: About to load: libhermes.so
11-24 07:03:40.668 26069-26107/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libhermes.so not found on /data/data/com.library_app2/lib-main
11-24 07:03:40.668 26069-26107/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libhermes.so not found on /data/app/com.library_app2-1/lib/arm
11-24 07:03:40.668 26069-26107/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libhermes.so not found on /system/vendor/lib
11-24 07:03:40.668 26069-26107/com.library_app2 D/SoLoader: libhermes.so not found on /system/lib
11-24 07:03:40.668 26069-26107/com.library_app2 E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
11-24 07:03:40.678 26069-26107/com.library_app2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.library_app2, PID: 26069
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:738)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:591)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:529)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:484)
        at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>(HermesExecutor.java:20)
        at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory.create(HermesExecutorFactory.java:27)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:952)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-24 07:03:40.678 1022-2704/? D/ActivityManager: addErrorToDropBox processName = com.library_app2
11-24 07:03:40.678 1022-2489/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from null to Window{39362e65 u0 com.library_app2/com.library_app2.MainActivity} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:3446 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:202 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:273 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:130 
11-24 07:03:40.678 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.698 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.698 1022-2704/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.library_app2/.MainActivity
11-24 07:03:40.698 26069-26105/com.library_app2 I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.099_msm8916_64_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.099__release_AU (Ib5665b357a)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
    Build Date: 11/13/15 Fri
    Local Branch: 
    Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.099
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
11-24 07:03:40.708 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.708 1022-26108/? D/DropBoxManagerService: file :: /data/system/dropbox/data_app_crash@1574553820706.txt
11-24 07:03:40.708 26069-26105/com.library_app2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-24 07:03:40.718 26069-26105/com.library_app2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-24 07:03:40.768 2531-2531/? W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f0b001d, entry index(29) is beyond type entryCount(23)
11-24 07:03:40.778 1022-1051/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{39362e65 u0 com.library_app2/com.library_app2.MainActivity} to Window{17b4c51d u0 Application Error: com.library_app2} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow:2696 com.android.server.wm.Session.addToDisplay:173 android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView:612 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView:300 
11-24 07:03:40.778 1022-1051/? W/ActivityManager:  Dismiss app error dialog : com.library_app2
11-24 07:03:40.798 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.808 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.818 1022-1040/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 144079(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 134MB/138MB, paused 2.940ms total 108.195ms
11-24 07:03:40.818 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.818 1022-1051/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{17b4c51d u0 Application Error: com.library_app2} to null Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2866 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2775 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2765 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:192 
11-24 07:03:40.818 26069-26107/com.library_app2 V/Process: killProcess [26069] Callers=com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:99 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690 <bottom of call stack> 
11-24 07:03:40.818 26069-26107/com.library_app2 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26069 SIG: 9
11-24 07:03:40.818 298-298/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/26069/oom_score_adj; errno=22
11-24 07:03:40.828 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.838 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.868 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.868 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.878 1022-1042/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{39362e65 u0 com.library_app2/com.library_app2.MainActivity}
11-24 07:03:40.878 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.878 1022-1984/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.library_app2 (pid 26069) has died
11-24 07:03:40.888 1022-1984/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecordLocked app:ProcessRecord{3a5807bc 26069:com.library_app2/u0a343}, restarting:false, allowRestart:true, index:-1
11-24 07:03:40.888 1022-1984/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecordLocked from:com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked:4985 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.appDiedLocked:5164 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient.binderDied:1373 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:551 
11-24 07:03:40.888 1022-1984/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecordLocked:goodbye proc com.library_app2
11-24 07:03:40.888 1022-1984/? D/ActivityManager: resumeTopActivityLocked: set keepResume to true.
11-24 07:03:40.888 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.898 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.908 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.918 1022-2005/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from null to Window{1786b351 u0 com.oppo.launcher/com.oppo.launcher.Launcher} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:3446 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:202 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:273 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:130 
11-24 07:03:40.918 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.918 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.928 1022-2721/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 26069 uid 10343
11-24 07:03:40.938 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.938 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.948 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.948 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.948 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.968 15968-15999/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:40.968 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:41.378 567-567/? I/MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ215 from CPU4 to CPU5
11-24 07:03:41.408 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:41.408 15968-15968/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: handleKeyguardVisibilityChanged mKeyguardViewManager = com.android.keyguard.KeyguardViewManager@12d66782
11-24 07:03:41.408 15968-15968/? D/KeyguardViewManager: handleKeyguardVisibilityChanged showing = true
11-24 07:03:41.408 15968-15988/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:41.418 15968-15987/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: setOccluded false
11-24 07:03:42.778 2531-2531/? W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC: Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? E/FullInputEventModel: onStartInput event aborted: dwa: could not obtain extracted text (class dwa)
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: >>>ANR MAY HAPPEN!!!<<<
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: >>>History msg List is:
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: History msg <1> { when=-2s24ms what=32 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler }, cost = 2024 ms
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: History msg <2> { when=0 what=45 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler arg1=1 }, cost = 0 ms
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: History msg <3> { when=0 what=45 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler }, cost = 0 ms
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: History msg <4> { when=-1ms what=20 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler }, cost = 1 ms
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: History msg <5> { when=-3ms what=40 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler }, cost = 3 ms
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: History msg <6> { when=-1ms what=30 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler }, cost = 0 ms
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: History msg <7> { when=0 what=110 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler }, cost = 0 ms
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: History msg <8> { when=-21ms what=32 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler }, cost = 21 ms
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: History msg <9> { when=0 what=45 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler arg1=1 }, cost = 0 ms
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: History msg <10> { when=0 what=45 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler }, cost = 0 ms
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: >>>HISTORY MSG DUMP OVER<<<
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: >>>Current msg List is:
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1>  = { when=-1s923ms what=110 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler }
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: Current msg <2>  = { when=-1s858ms what=30 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler }
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: Current msg <3>  = { when=-1s857ms what=20 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler obj=InputBinding{android.os.BinderProxy@39230931 / uid 10059 / pid 2779} }
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: Current msg <4>  = { when=-1s857ms what=45 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler arg1=1 obj=android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodSessionImpl@3cbe03e4 }
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: Current msg <5>  = { when=-1s857ms what=32 target=com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler obj=com.android.internal.os.SomeArgs@f70eec3 }
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? D/ANR_LOG: >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
11-24 07:03:42.798 2531-2531/? W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f0b001d, entry index(29) is beyond type entryCount(23)
11-24 07:03:43.218 2007-2007/? E/PhoneStatusBar: updateNotificationTitleText  preIsInsidePanelCanSlide =true,misInsidePanelCanSlide = true,misInsidePanelOpen = false
```

I have trying to figure out this few days, but no luck.

Please, any helps would be very appreciated.

Comment: What is the android version of the device you are testing?

Comment: I using Oppo R7sf, ColorOS version: V2.1.0i and Android Version 5.1.1

Comment: There is an issue opened on the react-native-image-picker repository on github related to it. 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/1185

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved this by added this line to: `myProjectName/android/app/build.gradle`

```
configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy {
       force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.0"
     }
}
```

I hope that information will be helpful for someone who also facing this issue in the future.

Answer (score 10):

For me just run a `./gradlew clean` made it work again

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When writing an answer, you may want to explain why you think your answer is correct, as it may be the case it is not targeting exactly the same problem and the explanation may help to see why

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic solution, you can use **logcat** either [from Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#systemLogView) or by running `adb logcat`. This allows you to view the stack trace for the crash, which often does not show up in Metro.

In my case I enabled `minifyEnabled` + Proguard, and could not identify which package was accidentally stripped. From the stacktrace, I could see `realm` was missing, which made it possible to search for the specific solution (ie. add `-keep class io.realm.react.**` to progard rules).

Answer (score 0):

go to android>app inside app delete build folder and rebuild the application again it worked for me very well.
Also you can look for gradlew clean